# Convert e.printStackTrace() to use log4j instead

Tags: java, log4j

I am very new to log4j.  I do not want to show exception stack trace in my log file such as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nodeRef is a mandatory parameter
at org.alfresco.util.ParameterCheck.mandatory(ParameterCheck.java:42)
```

These exceptions are written directly to console by using `e.printStackTrace()` like that

```
try {
    // something
} catch(Exception e) {
    StringWriter stack = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack));
    logger.debug("Caught exception; decorating with appropriate status template : " + stack.toString());
}
```

I am now **customizing a Open Source** project, not writing all my programs by myself. 
So it is impossible to remove `e.printStackTrace();` in all of java files.

As far as I know, log which are printed by `log4j` with logger can be configured by using log4j error level such as info, debug, warn.But how about writing directly to console or file?

**How can I configure log4j not to print only exception stacktrace but show other information? Is there a way to solve it out?**

Comment: You'd first need to **use** log4j. The catch statement you show a) doesn't use log4j; b) doesn't even print anything anywhere. It merely fills a StringWriter with the stacktrace.

Comment: I changed my code. My sample uses both e.printStackTrace() and logger.debug(). It is not written by me. My project uses that jar file whose attached source is shown like that.

Comment: What I would do is to create a PrintStream to replace System.err which writes everything it gets to log4j.  That way you can use System.out or System.err any way you like and it actually uses log4j. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code

```
StringWriter stack = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack));
logger.debug("Caught exception; decorating with appropriate status template : " + stack.toString());
```

is just an example of plain wrong usage of the Log4j API. But, if you are stuck with it, there will be nothing for you to do except raise the log level above `debug` and leave out the entire message.

There may **possibly** be a way to *truncate* all log messages, which would somewhat alleviate your problem.

Comment: Yeah. Because we already used logger.debug(). I think we do not need to use e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack)); But the source already used like that.

Comment: I don't think you dig that code. Nothing is redundant here; `printStackTrace` in your example doesn't actually **print** anything. The programmer just wanted a stacktrace appended to a `debug` log message, where Log4J doesn't support `log.debug(msg, exc)`---and for good reason.

Answer (score 8):

Use Logger#error

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

...

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Locomotive.class);
log.error("your message", exc);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
logger.info("Inside add() of Abc class");
logger.error("Error occurred while calculation::::"+errorMessage);
```